# How do I develop a plug-in for QtWebKit?

Tags: qt, plugins, webkit, qtwebkit

I am trying to develop a plug-in for [QtWebkit](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKit). But I am not able to find how to develop a plugin for QtWebKit, hopefully one that can be invoked by JavaScript.  Does anyone know of any tutorials or documents that explain how to do this?

Webkit has been intregated into Qt and this integrated package is called QtWebkit. They have provided new method for for plugin creation.

-Regards, Vivek Gupta

Comment: Was my comment helpful at all?

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is to write a subclass of `QWebPage` and set this on your `webview`. Then you can show your own HTML page and react to the appropriate object tag in the [`createPlugin`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qwebpage.html#createPlugin) method;

```
protected:
   QObject* createPlugin(const QString &classid, const QUrl &url, const QStringList &paramNames, const QStringList &paramValues)
   {
      if (classid=="lineedit") {
         QLineEdit *lineedit = new QLineEdit;
         return lineedit;
      }
      return 0;
}
```

and show something like the following HTML;

```
<object type="application/x-qt-plugin" classid="lineedit" id="lineedit">
can't load plugin
</object>
```

Remember you need to turn on plugins, and possibly also JavaScript if you want more advanced functionality in the [`QWebSettings`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qwebsettings.html#WebAttribute-enum)

To have more advanced functionality, you should use a [`QWebPluginFactory`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qwebpluginfactory.html)

Answer (score 1):

Actually Webkit has been intregated in Qt and this intregated package is called QtWebkit.
And they have provided new method for for plugin creation.I just need a link or steps for creating a plugin in QtWebkit and that plugin should be invoked by java script.

Regards
Vivek Gupta

Answer (score 0):

[Introduction to WebKit Plug-in Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/WebKit_PluginProgTopic/WebKitPluginTopics.html) is for WebKit, is QtWebKit that special?

Answer (score 0):

To expose the object to Javascript, use

```
this->mainFrame()->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("lineedit", this);
```

where `lineedit` is the name that can be used to access the object from javascript

Qt properties will be exposed as JavaScript properties and slots as JavaScript methods.
(see http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qwebframe.html#addToJavaScriptWindowObject)